# nextcloudcmd cron job not running

Tags: command-line, cron

I'm just trying to set up a nextcloud folder sync on a ubuntu server with terminal only. The command I'm using to sync is the following:

```
nextcloudcmd -h --trust -u <user> -p '<password>' /home/git/nextcloud/ https://192.168.1.10/remote.php/webdav/Backup
```

I'm having some weird characters in my password, that's why I need the ''.

To my question: If I'm running the command everything works fine. But when using cron, the command just is not executed.

```
* * * * * nextcloudcmd -h --trust -u <user> -p '<password>' /home/git/nextcloud/ https://192.168.1.10/remote.php/webdav/Backup >> /tmp/nclog 2>&1
```

With this command, nothing happens, the log file is not created.

```
* * * * * nextcloudcmd /tmp/nclog 2>&1
```

Weirdly, this command creates the logfile and seems to be running.

Does anyone have a idea, what's going wrong here?

Comment: *"I'm having some weird characters in my password"* is `%` one of them?

Comment: Yes indeed... I just googled it... so I have to use \%. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try putting the **full path** of the `nextcloudcmd` command in *crontab*? To find out the full path user `whereis nextcloudcmd`